# How to verify a number on a web-page using robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I need to verify a number on a web-page, can anyone helpe me? Do i get the ID of the number and then conver this into an int then log to console?

```
Log To Console
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example, I need to verify there are 1000 people registered on a web page, this number is located on the home page and I need to verify the number is present

Comment: @Ashy0 You should Edit your question with more information, like the example you replied to the Community Bot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SeleniumLibrary, you can use the keyword:

```
${myvalue}=    Get Text    <locator for the number>
```

Or, if you just want to check if the Element is there:

```
Page Should Contain Element    <locator for the number>
```

See the [SeleniumLibrary keywords doc](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html)